# I want to make a scatter graph of the output of ftrace (from kernel)

Tags: excel

I want to make a scatter graph of the output of ftrace (from kernel) on asm_do_IRQ..The problem is there are 8000+ entries and I get the results as a single line plot. Is there any way to do a normalisation of the values so that I can get a scatter plot? The values I want to print are as below:

```
Interrupt        Time  
uart-pl011     196.98111  
Nomadi         196.983246  
prcmu          196.983307  
dma40          196.983429  
dma40          196.984222  
Nomadi         196.98642  
dma40          196.988922  
prcmu          196.988953
```

since the number of values are huge, excel takes time on the Y axis and plots the number of interrupts on the X axis. But i want the interrupts by name on the Y axis and time on the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is not possible. Scatter graphs can only be used to plot two variables, and since one of the axes i want to plot is a string, this is not possible - i can only get a trend, not the exact plots vs time